# Where does Docker install gems on a mac

Tags: docker-compose

I have searched and cant seem to find where Docker installs the gem files on a Mac.  One of the gems I uses has a minor bug that needs to be changed to work so trying to find the gem files to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker doesn't install any gems onto your actual Mac. It will install them inside a container, or a volume if you have set that up.

Given your scenario, it may be easier to fork the Gem's repo, make the changes you need, and the update your fork. Once you have your forked repo the way you want, you can specify that as the gem's source in your Gemfile using the git link.

Example:

```
gem 'nokogiri', :git => 'https://github.com/<yournname>/nokogiri.git'
```

[Gems from git repos](http://bundler.io/git.html)

[Persistent Ruby Gems Container with Docker](https://www.healthcareblocks.com/blog/persistent-ruby-gems-docker-container)

Comment: after playing around I figured out how to get the docker image to recognize the bundle install and say the fork was checkedout...though there are some problems with impressionist that I had to work out with their master fork being broken...so yay